# Updating fabricjs object coordinates while moving

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to get the x and y coordinates of the object while its moving. I use `getLeft()` and `getTop()` methods on `object:moving`. But these methods don't help if the object is rotated.

Then I tried getting the top and left of the bounding box of the object using `object.getBoundRect().top`. But this doesn't get updated dynamically. It gives the bounding box value at the beginning of move operation. Is there a way to get the bounding box value while moving?

```
canvas.on('object:moving', function(e) {
  var scaledObject = e.target;
  $('#mouse-info').text("X:"+parseInt(scaledObject.getBoundingRect().left)+", Y:"+parseInt(scaledObject.getBoundingRect().top));
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Fabric.js version 2.4.4, the `getLeft()` and `getTop()` methods have been removed from the Fabric Object class. The properties top and left are updated on the `object:moving` event, so you can access them directly; however, these properties reflect the `aCoords`, or Absolute Coordinates, of the Fabric Object without any regard to how the zoom value of the canvas changes that Object's coordinates.

The `oCoords` take into account a Fabric Object's position including that Object's `viewportTransform` and `padding` properties.

Despite the fact that the Fabric.js [documentation](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#oCoords) currently claims, "You can calculate [the `oCoords`] without updating with @method calcCoords," the `oCoords` do not in fact appear to be updated by the `object:moving` event.

You therefore need to call the `calcCoords` method on the object returned by the event in order to get coordinates which account for the canvas zoom value and object padding.

**Here is a working solution:**

```
fabricCanvas.on("object:moving", function(e) {
    var actObj = e.target;
    var coords = actObj.calcCoords(); 
    // calcCoords returns an object of corner points like this 
    //{bl:{x:val, y:val},tl:{x:val, y:val},br:{x:val, y:val},tr:{x:val, y:val}}
    var left = coords.tl.x;
    var top = coords.tl.y;
    return {left:left,top:top};
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I found this answer after a few days I asked the question. But I'm accepting this answer since its correct and answers for the current version of Fabric

Answer (score 0):

Sammy,

You are doing something wrong. getTop and getLeft work fine for version 1.7

Check this code:

```
canvas.on('object:moving',function(e){
    if (e.target){
        console.log(e.target.getTop());
      console.log(e.target.getLeft());
    }
 });
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to have with rotating you have to do after each render:

```
canvas.on('after:render', function() {
    canvas.contextContainer.strokeStyle = '#555';
    canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
      var bound = obj.getBoundingRect();
      canvas.contextContainer.strokeRect(
        bound.left + 0.5,
        bound.top + 0.5,
        bound.width,
        bound.height
      );
    });

    var ao = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if (ao) {
    var bound = ao.getBoundingRect();
     console.log(bound.left);
     console.log(bound.top);
   }   
  });
```

This code will draw for you bounding box for each shape after each render. If you want to hide bounding box just delete this code:

```
canvas.contextContainer.strokeStyle = '#555';
        canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
          var bound = obj.getBoundingRect();
          canvas.contextContainer.strokeRect(
            bound.left + 0.5,
            bound.top + 0.5,
            bound.width,
            bound.height
          );
        });
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eA3xH/101/)

Hopefully, it will help you.

Comment: I still get the output. But it is incorrect since left of object changes when it is rotated.

Comment: Check updated post. I did updates instead of using object:moving use after:render